# (Z-Transform of a sequence) What does my lecturer mean here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

I'm reading some lecture notes my lecture posted online on **Z Transforms** and here's what one of the notes says:

> We may differentiate a sequence  $\space {x_n} = {a^n} \space$ with respect to $\space a \space$ to get $\space {{dx_n}\over da} = na^{n-1} \space$.

Here's where he lost me completely:

> Then:
>
> $$\space (na^{n-1}) = {d\over da} Z(a^n) = {d\over da} {z\over {z-a}} = {z\over {(z-a)^2}} \space$$

How is $ \space (na^{n-1}) = {d\over da} Z(a^n) \space$?

Isn't that assuming that:

$$a^{n} = Z(a^{n})$$

Comment: You're correct.  $Z(na^{n-1})=\frac{d}{da}Z(a^n)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV - That's what I also thought it should be. Perhaps a typo haha.